# Is it possible to combine different language in one application?

Tags: java, php, node.js, microservices

first of all, i dont want to make things a bit ambiguous.

is it possible to to use different language such node.js, php for developing a Web service?

for instance the node.js will be responsible for user authentication and PHP and responsible messaging .
mainly the idea of the app will be in Microservice architecture.
The Node.js will have the authentication service
and the PHP will have the messaging service.
is that a good idea
because i am learning microservices architecure and i got the user authentication and i was thinking of use PHP to complete the rest of my project.
Obviously they will have a different DB.
thanks in advance

Comment: you can combine as many as you like, as long as you find a way to pass data between them (ex: pass json_encoded data from one to another)

Comment: Microservices exist for that purpose: They are micro applications which work on their own, and can be programmed in any programming language.

Comment: "is it possible to to use different language such node.js, php for developing andriod app" -- not really. You can use those technologies for developing a **server** that might be used by an Android app.

Comment: Node.js is not a language, but a framework. The given language is JavaScript, hence the "js" extension.

Comment: @CommonsWare 41 , i know that Node nor PHP are not used to to build andriod app, but they are used to develop a backend services . i know that andriod app are built in java. but anyway, thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question..Yes 
infact, a polyglot approach is recommended. this will help you not get obsolete with new tech & adopt new programming languages which may server different functional needs.

Having said this, you need to be be careful & cautious about the pitfalls of microservice design.(granularity of services, Eventual data consistency, deployment pipeline, containerization, service catalog, service registries, dynamic load-balancing  and service granularity etc.,)

node.js is getting very popular on MSA

-Good Luck

Comment: *a polyglot approach is recommended* - and yet, in very few companies do you ever see this.